# How to automate addition of [skip ci] to commit messages on some branch in git

Tags: git, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am working on a branch which does not touch any source code at all, it merely contributes to the documentation of the project. As such, there is no point in wasting my CI provider's CPU cycles and clogging up the queue. I know that I can do this by adding `[skip ci]` to the commit message, but I always forget to do it at commit time. Some time later, the message from the CI bot arrives and I slap myself for having forgotten once more.

Surely there must be a better way!

I am thinking of using a Git hook to add `[skip ci]` to any commit message on this branch.

My questions are:

1. Is there some better way forward?
2. Surely, I am not the first to want to do this. I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Is there some prior art?
3. If both the previous questions' answers are 'no', do you have any advice on writing the actual hook?

I'm using Travis CI.

Comment: Who is your CI provider? (And what software do they run, if that is non-obvious?)

Comment: @ScottWeldon my CI provider in this case is Travis, though I don't see how that makes a difference, as the `[skip ci]` has to be added to the commit message, i.e. *before* the CI provider gets involved, and this is the case for all providers that support `[skip ci]`.

Comment: My answer should explain why I asked about the provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to automate the addition of `[skip ci]` to your commit messages (see e.g. [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/26166223/2747593)), but I don't think that's the best solution here. You said:

> I am working on a branch which does not touch any source code at all, it merely contributes to the documentation of the project.

Thus, there is really no need to *ever* trigger any builds on such branches.

It's easy to [specify which branches to build or not build](//docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Building-Specific-Branches), but this must be configured in advance, and you must know which branches to block.

The solution to those two issues is [everyone's favorite tool, regular expressions](//stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2747593). Add something like this to your `.travis.yml`:

```yaml
branches:
  except:
    - /^feature\/docs\/.*$/
```

(See also [the Travis CI docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Using-regular-expressions).)

Then whenever you want to write documentation, create a branch that starts with `feature/docs/` and it won't be built by Travis CI.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to deal with pull requests on such branches in repos which have been configured to require CI checks? The required check is waiting for a build that will never take place.

Comment: @jacg The only idea I have currently is to either rename the branch or create a duplicate branch pointing to the same commit. The status checks are attached to commits, not branches, so doing either of those should work.

Comment: Hmm, I think my last comment was a false alarm: PRs that merge into master *will* be built (as we're no longer on the docs branch), while pull requests into a docs branch shouldn't need to be built, because you won't require builds on that branch.